# Убрать кавычки в параметре макроса

Tags: c++, рефлексия, макросы

Как убрать кавычки в параметре макроса?

Пример:

```
MACRO("std::cout << 42;")
```

Надо чтобы макрос удалял кавычки и вставлял код как есть.

Comment: Зачем вам это понадобилось? Почему бы не передавать параметры как есть или вообще отказаться от макросов?

Comment: @user7860670 надо из строк выполнять

Comment: "надо из строк выполнять" - вопрос остается - Зачем вам это понадобилось?

Comment: @user7860670 у меня есть строка, надо выполнить то что в ней без кавычек

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14323474/2881286

Comment: Чтобы выполнить строку вам понадобится собрать новую программу или библиотеку с помощью компилятора С++. Макросы в С++ производят только простую текстовую подстановку, при чем в начале компиляции этой программы.

Comment: А если бы такая возможность была (на самом деле есть обратная - заключить в кавычки), то как бьы вы ею пользовались? Покажите пример.

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы выполнить строку вам понадобится собрать новую программу или библиотеку с помощью компилятора С++. Макросы в С++ производят только простую текстовую подстановку, при чем в начале компиляции этой программы.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323474/c-macro-that-removes-quotes-from-input